# When I press button Start it should go to next activity but it goes to home screen

Tags: java, android

When I press button Start It should go to next activity but it goes to home screen. This problem I faced when I have added banner ad code.

The Button which is named as startbtn in XML code and btnclk1 in Java code. I am doing this project in Android Studio.

XML Code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/splashscr"
    tools:context=".SplashScreen">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startbtn2"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:text="Show Ad"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.625" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="239dp"
        android:layout_height="221dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.287"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/criclive" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="288dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.507"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/credits" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startbtn"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:text="Start"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.559" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="325dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-8972808858904277/7753758329"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Java code:

```
    package com.airobotfyp.livecricket;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;


public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    private AdView mAdView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
        Button btnclk1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startbtn);
        Button btnclk2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startbtn2);

        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-8972808858904277~8136901702");

        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        AdView adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-8972808858904277/7753758329");
        mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdOpened() {
                // Code to be executed when an ad opens an overlay that
                // covers the screen.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLeftApplication() {
                // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                // Code to be executed when the user is about to return
                // to the app after tapping on an ad.
            }
        });
        //full
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-8972808858904277/3431369930");
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                // Load the next interstitial.
                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            }
        });
        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdOpened() {
                // Code to be executed when the ad is displayed.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLeftApplication() {
                // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                // Code to be executed when when the interstitial ad is closed.
            }
        });

        btnclk1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                } else {
                    Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
                }
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,Menu.class);
                startActivity(mainIntent);
            }
        });
        btnclk2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                } else {
                    Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: *`When I press button Start It should go to next activity but It goes to home screen`* It means your app is crashing check the logcat for error Have a look **[Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)**

Comment: Can you help me how can i use logcat?

Comment: *`how can i use logcat`*  than check  this https://stackoverflow.com/a/23353174/7666442

Comment: Hey I have got a red line here: All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 28.0.0, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 and com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0 less... (Ctrl+F1) 
There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular.

Comment: The accepted answer to this question is plainly not an answer to the question that was asked. On that basis alone, the question should be put on hold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Logcat]
This is where the logcat resides. PLease post the error that might be popping up in the logcat here.

Comment: This does not provide answer to the question, it should be a comment and BTW read this [answer]

Comment: I think the lad just needed some visuals to get a head start. So thought of adding it up here. Remember the time when we had a hard time finding the build variants option. BTW visuals always help. Cheerio

Comment: @Nilesh Rathod please can you see my problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54633202/how-to-set-mediaplayer-notification-with-mediasession-and-notificationcompat-med You already help me last time